# Reload a web app from another web app in Google apps Scripr

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Hello and thanks for your help in advance. That's the problem: I have two web apps (GAS + JS) with the same database made with Google sheets.  One is a dashboard and the other is a control panel. Both run separately consulting the data when is necessary and the dashboard has a setInterval to reload the data. Is there any way to reload the dashboard when the control panel write data in the database in order to avoid the SetInterval and update it automatically? Thanks again.

I was thinking to use libraries but I don't know if the library will be inherited when I clone the web app.
I was thinking to get the url of the dashboard and force reload from the control panel but I don't know if this trick will work.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create two web apps in the same project?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Each web app is in a different project but read the same database.

Comment: So both webapps have a client side and a server side.   So you must realize that the clientside is event driven and any access to it must come as a response to a request from it.  Seems like you should be able to communicate via the Spreadsheet to let the other webapp know that it's time to update it's data.  But either way it will have to poll the spreadsheet to see when the data has been updated.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I do actually. Anyway, your comment bring me an idea. Thanks.